# Angular: How to combine data structures in a simple way

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to combine two data structures inside of a modal. The first data structure is passed into the modal, the second one will be fetched from server.

At the moment it looks like that:

TS File:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  entries: IGuiEntry[];
  entriesAdditionalInfo$: Observable<EntryAdditionalInfo[]>;

  constructor( private backendService: BackendService,
               @Inject( MAT_DIALOG_DATA ) private data: {  entries: IGuiEntry[] } ) { 
    this.entries = data.entries;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.entriesAdditionalInfo$ = this.backendService.getEntriesAdditionalInfo();
  }

  getAdditionalInfo( entriesAdditionalInfo: EntryAdditionalInfo[], entryId: number ): AdditionalInfo[] {
    return entriesAdditionalInfo.find( e => e.id=== entryId)?.additionalInfo;
  }

}
```

HTML File:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Additional Info Summary</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
  
  <div *ngIf="( entriesAdditionalInfo$ | async ) as entriesAdditionalInfo">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of entries; let i = index">

      <div *ngIf="getAdditionalInfo( entriesAdditionalInfo, entry.id) as additionalInfos">
          // do something with the entries additional informations.
      </div>

    </ng-container>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Here are some of my questions:

I start with the iteration over the entries (which were passed into the modal). This is important, because the resulting rows must have the order of the entries.

Afterwards I make a subscription to the AdditionalInfo and save the response as the local variable entiresAdditionalInfo. This request will be fired once for all entries.

In the next div I search the corresponding additional infos for the current entry in the loop. This happens in a function call.
Here is my first question:
This function call will only be made, when the data of the entries have changed, not on every Change Detection loop?

The next question:
Is it a good practise to use this function here? Or should I build the whole structure already in the components ngOnInit function? The main question for me is, if this is already to complex for the view and should be calculate all in the components code.

Maybe there is a much simplier approach for this kind of use case?

Answer (score 1):

`This function call will only be made, when the data of the entries have changed, not on every Change Detection loop?`

Whenever this line of code will be rendered the function will run every single time. That's reply to your next question as well. We try to avoid functions inside template.

To fix this, I would suggest you to create a custom pipe to solve your problem in a more efficient way.

Comment: so in order to avoid performance issues I sould either build my whole data structure in the onInit function (which includes the subscriptions to the webservices), or use pure pipes. Is that correct?

Comment: You could either write code to trace data on Angular life-cycle hooks and on event emissions or use `pipes` that in your code, I believe that this is the best choice.